# Run script on multiple ec2 instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

It seems that I have python 2.6 on my ec2-cluster.

I want to update it to python 2.7 + update some other python libraries.

For example,running some apt-get commands.

What would be the best way for doing that? Obviously, I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: I'd suggest experimenting with configuration management, and would recommend Ansible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this I usually use [clusterssh](https://github.com/duncs/clusterssh).  It is quick and easy. No magic involved.

I am not sure if amazon has some builtin solution for this.

Comment: I can just give the public dns of my instacnes and the commands I want to run and it will work?

Comment: Yes. Add them to the `~/.ssh/config with` appropriate names, then make clusters in `.clusterssh/clusters` in style `clusterName client1 client2 client3`. Then just run `cssh clusterName`. It will open terminal for each client plus one master window - if you type something there, it will copy it to all instances.